# Rails: Programatically caching friendly urls on facebook when using friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, friendly-id

I have a view page which has an embedded youtube video on it. I have the proper OG tags so that the video is embedded on facebook when shared.

But in order for above to work, I need to programatically hit the Facebook debugger endpoint so that my url gets cached.

I've created an after_create on my Movie model:

```
after_create :facebook_cache

def facebook_cache
    FacebookCacheUrl.call(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.movie_url(self))
end
```

The issue that I'm encountering is that my app is sending Facebook the friendly url, e.g. `www.mysite.com/movies/friendly-movie-title`. But at the time the app sends the url, the page is showing a 404. So Facebook is caching the server error page info.

Later in the lifecycle, the url works properly.

My question is where should I be pinging the Facebook debugger so that it happens as soon as possible without leading to a 404?

Comment: _“My question is where should I be pinging the Facebook debugger so that it happens as soon as possible without leading to a 404?”_ – as soon as your system _doesn’t_ respond with a 404 for that URL any more …? It is your system, so you should know best when that is, right?

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking. It's Rails. I thought an after_create callback would be after the URL has been generated. But it's not, so I'm asking...